# Document Scroll Issues (typing animation / making div do something)

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

This question is focused on this issue i'm experiencing when I try to execute my code.

1. Coding for fun / practice (I am new to jQuery)
2. Somehow messed up
3. here is my story

my code so far...

```
var position = $("#second").offset();
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y >= position.top) {
        //text that belongs on second slide
        var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sagittis sodales ex vel pellentesque. Vestibulum quis arcu odio. Curabitur feugiat lorem quis luctus faucibus. ";

        //text is split up to letters
        $.each(text.split(""), function (i, letter) {

            //we add 100*i ms delay to each letter 
            setTimeout(function () {

                //we add the letter to the container
                $("#text").html($("#text").html() + letter);
            }, 80 * i);
        });
    }
});
```

The idea was to make the text start doing the "typewriter" animation once you clicked on a button to scroll to the next slide. It works fine, but only when I press the button. If I scroll down with my mouse the code goes crazy. See here: [preview from where i host my code](http://previewformycode.tumblr.com) / [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poolsxx/octoe1Lc/1/)

You can scroll down and the text won't go crazy in the JSfiddle, but not on the website I host my code. However, if you scroll back up and scroll back down on the JSfiddle the text will go crazy.

Also, yes, I know blinking text is frowned upon, please don't comment on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because everytime you scroll up and down (in the fiddle) the function is firing again and again. A simple solution is to use a variable as a check. Set some variable tok `false` and when you scroll if that variable is equal to `false`, then run the script and set it to `true` (so it won't fire again)

```
var triggered = false;

...

if(y >= position.top && triggered === false){
   triggered = true; //the above line will return false and won't fire the function
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/octoe1Lc/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much, I mean it. This has helped a ton, and I'm sure will come in handy in the future.